# adding CSS to XML and upload to Saxonica

Tags: html, css, xml

Trying to add CSS to XML and upload to Saxonica to get a HTML output. Everytime I try I get an error from Saxonica: SEPM0004: When 'standalone' or 'doctype-system' is specified, the document must be
  well-formed; but this document contains a top-level text node
When 'standalone' or 'doctype-system' is specified, the document must be well-formed; but this document contains a top-level text node
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="measurements4.css"?>
<measurements>
 <measurement typeOfMeasurement="disType">  
    <distance measureDistance="imperial">1.45</distance>
 </measurement>
 <measurement typeOfMeasurement="weiType">
    <weight measureWeight="troy">.6</weight>
 </measurement>
 <measurement typeOfMeasurement="disType">
    <distance measureDistance="metric">25</distance>
 </measurement>
</measurements>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" doctype-public="htmlPUBLIC//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/html">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <title>Measurements through XML to HMTL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="measurements4.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <p>The three measurements that I want transformed.</p>
    <p>There are 2 distance measurements</p>
    <p>There is 1 weight measurement</p>
   </body>
  </html> 
    <p>A weight measurement using the <span><xsl:value-of select="/weight/@measureWeight"/></span> scale is:</p><br />
    <h3>The amount of weight is <span><xsl:value-of select="//weight"/></span></h3><br />
   <xsl:for-each select="/measurements/measurement">
   <xsl:if test="distance">
    <p>A distance measurement using the <span><xsl:value-of select="distance/@measureDistance"/></span> scale is:</p><br />
    <h3>The length of distance is <span><xsl:value-of select="distance"/></span></h3><br />
    <p><xsl:apply-templates select="measurements/measurement"/></p>
   </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

css:

```
distance{
   display:block; border-style:solid; border-width:3px; float:left; width:45%;}
weight{
   display:block; border-style:solid; border-width:3px; float:right; width:45%;}
imperial{
   display:inline; border-style:solid; border-width:3px; float:left; width:30%;}
metric{
   display:inline; border-style:solid; border-width:3px; float:left; width:30%;}
gram{
   display:inline; border-style:solid; border-width:3px; float:right; width:30%;}
troy{
   display:inline; border-style:solid; border-width:3px; float:right; width:30%;}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we need to see details of how you are executing the various processes you describe as "add CSS to XML and upload to Saxonica". How are you "adding CSS to XML" and what is the output? I don't know any way of adding CSS to XML: you can apply CSS to XML in the browser, but the output is a rendered page on the screen, not a document that you can "upload to Saxonica" (whatever that means).

Comment: The error "this document contains a top-level text node" sounds like you inadvertently typed something, maybe a non-breaking space, in the xml file that shouldn't be there. Either before or after the measurements element.